# jQuery not refreshing the dropdown list on the jQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have code below. There are two dropdown lists on the popup jQuery Dialog form. I use  jQuery to populate them. The issue is when I click the edit icon(on each product item right side) sometime it can show the selected item on the popup dropdown list, but sometime not. Check the code using firebug, it shows jQuery already change the code, but the screen not show the selected item.

```
function getProductById(ProductId) {
    $.getJSON("GetProductById", { ProductId: ProductId }, function populateProduct(data) {
        //Populate query result retreved from server into a Sub form for edit
        $("#ProductName").val(data.ProductName);
        $("#UnitPrice").val(data.UnitPrice);
        $("#Discontinued").attr("checked", data.Discontinued);

        $("#Supplier option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#Supplier option[value=" + "\"" + data.Supplier + "\"" + "]").attr("selected", "selected");

        $("#Categorie option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#Categorie option[value=" + "\"" + data.Category + "\"" + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
    });
};
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be a number of things. First, try using `.prop('selected', 'selected')` instead of `.attr("selected", "selected")`

Comment: @Victor. I appreciate your helping very much! It works now! So why my code is not work but after change to .prop('selected', 'selected') works?

Comment: None of this is necessary. If `data.Supplier` contains a value that matches one of the options values in the Supplier dropdown, then all you need is `$("#Supplier').val(data.Supplier);` and ditto for `Category`

Comment: It all depends on a Browser and jQuery versions you using but I think `attr`is deprecated now

Comment: `attr` is not depreciated

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks! Your way also work! And this is a much simple way than my old one.

Comment: Also, I would consider replacing `attr` with `prop` for a checkbox if you using jQuery 1.9+. http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-

Comment: @Victor please add a answer post, so I can give your guys credit for the helping.

Comment: @Victor thanks for remainder, I did change attr to prop on the checkbox.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your way is the best solution but Mr. victor provide a way to solve the issue first, so I would give him creit for answer the question if you do not mind. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.9+ replace `attr` with `prop` which is only there for backward compatibility and likely will be removed in a near future: [.attr vs .prop](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-). So, instead of `.attr("checked", data.Discontinued);` try using `.prop("checked", data.Discontinued);` and replace `.attr("selected", "selected")` with `.prop("selected", "selected")`